# How to change number to time and day of the week in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json response that requires that I change '0900' to 9:00am and '1300' to 1:00pm, 5 to Friday

```
{

      'start': '0900',
      'end': '1300',
      'day' : 5

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more

Comment: This a sample of the response from an api get request. I need to convert these value to datetime value to display the respective times and day of the week on a flutter app ui

Comment: If possible, changing the API response would be the right call here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
 print(_convertToTime("1300"));
 print(_convertToTime("0900"));
  
  
  
 var days ={
      0  : "Sunday",
      1  : "Monday",
      2  : "Tuesday",
      3  : "Wednesday",
      4  : "Thursday",
      5  : "Friday",
      6  : "Saturday",
 };
  
  print(days[5]);

 
 _convertToTime(String key) {
   
    var d = key.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r".{2}"), (match) => "${match.group(0)} ");
  
  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("HH mm");
  var dateTime = dateFormat.parse(d);
  DateFormat dateFormatTarget = DateFormat("hh:mm a");
  return dateFormatTarget.format(dateTime);
 }
```

Comment: the day key s supposed to be used a calendar view package and ought to be in calendar format and not hard coded https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view

Comment: You have only day number not whole date thats why its created like that. if you have full date in response then can use DateTime instead of this

Comment: Alright. However, what if i have to convert the day number to days of the week irrespective of the date

Comment: if it will be like 2022-01-01 09:00:00 then you just have to use date time. If no date then we can't get exact day of week

Comment: An addition to this solution is to install the intl flutter package

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I prefer using `TimeOfDay`.

First,  let's get start and end from map.

```dart
  late TimeOfDay start;
  late TimeOfDay end;

  TimeOfDay stringToTimeOfDay(String value) {
    return TimeOfDay(
      hour: int.tryParse(value.substring(0, 2)) ?? 0,
      minute: int.tryParse(value.substring(2)) ?? 0,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    start = stringToTimeOfDay(data["start"].toString());
    end = stringToTimeOfDay(data["end"].toString());
  }
```

Now the time will be in 24 formats. To convert in string and for 12 formats, you can use `hourOfPeriod`. I am using extension, customize the way you like.

```dart
extension TimeOfDayExtension on TimeOfDay {
  ///convert to 12h then and formatting string 00:00
  String get formatToString {
    final h = replacing(hour: hourOfPeriod).hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final m = replacing(hour: hourOfPeriod).minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return "$h:$m${period.name}";
  }
}
```

And use-case will be

```dart
Text(start.formatToString),
Text(end.formatToString),
```